# How can I test and debug my syntax files?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to make a syntax file for [Raku](https://raku.org/). The major challenge I'm running into is that I have no automated means to test that my highlighting works as expected. I have to keep another tab open, switch to it, source the syntax file, and then visually inspect the highlighting.

I would like some way to specify what I want the highlighting to look like and then run an automated test to verify that a syntax file does or does not produce the expected results.

Comment: My [testing.vim](https://github.com/arp242/testing.vim) program can test syntax files; AFAIK that's the easiest way (but I'm probably biased as I'm the author of that )

Comment: I used some basic screen-testing for the xml-runtime files, see e.g. [here](https://github.com/chrisbra/vim-xml-runtime). this is based havily on the Vim testing framework but much more simplified

Comment: Have you seen [Swatch.vim](https://github.com/joelstrouts/swatch.vim) (neovim only)? It doesn't do _testing_ per se, but it should a). allow you to specify the highlighting, and b). presuming it works as described, make "testing" unnecessary?